# How to print the grand total only in the last page of a very long report?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

How can I make the total paramater appear only on the last page of a report with lots of concepts.

The report repeats istelf until the list of concepts is displayed in two or more pages. The total appears in all of them because the parameter (received as $PTotal) is on the footer of the page.

I need this to be displayed only in the footer of the last page. It doesnt matter if I leave that space as blank, I just need the parameter to be displayed only at the last page.

This is not a report composed of varios pages, it generates multiple pages until the list fits. Just to clarify.

[image]

How can I fix that parameter tag with a printWhenExpression tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy your footer band and rename it to a lastPageFooter band. Keep the original footer intact, but delete the textField for $P{total} from it. The lastPageFooter band, including your total, will only be printed on the last page of the report.

Comment: This is what I used, it looks dirty, but it works :P. Thank you!

Comment: It's dirty of course, as the printout is at the footer and leave a lot of blank space if the detail page not close too and sometimes it's printed on Summary band which is not as expected.

Answer (score 5):

If you just use the summary-band for this purpose?

```
  .......
  <summary>
    <band height="146" splitType="Stretch">
      <reportElement .../>
       <textElement ...>
         <font .../>
       </textElement>
       <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{total}]]>           </textFieldExpression>
    </band>
  </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a PrintWhenExpression of

```
$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == $V{PAGE_COUNT}
```

Comment: I'm already using the <textFieldExpression> tags, where should I put it? Or could I use the script block within the textfield tag?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, this approach won't work: Per the docs (http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRVariable.html#PAGE_COUNT), PAGE_COUNT is "Built-in variable containing the number of records that were processed when generating the current page" -- *not* the total count of pages in the report.

Comment: Get total of the pages, can see here: https://ask.osify.com/qa/11177 but it won't be able to use in Print Expression, as the calculation seems to do page by page that make the print expression cannot do, but it can be used on design view.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use "Last Page Footer" band